# Holder.js doesn't work with turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, holder.js

Holder.js doesn't work with turbolinks.

I'm getting empty images.

It works when i press Ctrl+R.

How to get them work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script to run holder.js between requests:

```
$(document).bind 'page:change', ->
  Holder.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5 I had to use this:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
    Holder.run()
});
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18770589/1845011 and https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installing-javascript-behavior